# How to install libOpenCL.so on ubuntu

Tags: opencl

I downloaded `intel_sdk_for_opencl_2016_ubuntu_6.0.0.1049_x64`, tried to run `install.sh` but it says Unsupported OS, so I then read somewhere that I needed to make .deb file from one of the RPM files, I did it with 2:

opencl-1.2-devel_6.0.0.1049-2_amd64.deb

opencl-1.2-intel-devel_6.0.0.1049-2_amd64.deb

Installed them both with `sudo dpkg -i`, but I still don't have the libOpenCL.so that I need

Now I'm stuck... :(

Answer (score 99, accepted):

It looks like `libOpenCL.so` is provided by the `ocl-icd-opencl-dev` package. To install this package, run:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ocl-icd-opencl-dev
```

Now libOpenCL.so should be located at `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOpenCL.so`

Comment: Also there is python3-pyopencl to use opencl with python / numpy , and drivers for nvidia graphics cards,  for c development you will need opencl-headers .. those may be optional for the generic driver listed @Nick Weinberg

Comment: Thank you very much! Funny in my research I never found a simple answer like that... would you mind telling me if there is a similar way to install cuda as well? Thanks!

Comment: You can take a look at the packages here: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=cuda&searchon=names&suite=xenial&section=all , but I'm not sure which one you need. If you're looking for a specific file provided by a package (like you were looking for `libOpenCL.so`) there's a "list of files" link on each package's detail page that comes in handy.

Comment: Seems like it removed `nvidia-opencl-dev` and installed `ocl-icd-opencl-dev` for me. Is that what we want? `clinfo` did not detect anything, either before or after

Comment: FWIW I needed more packages and I found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/850281/opencl-on-ubuntu-16-04-intel-sandy-bridge-cpu) question to be helpful

Answer (score 13):

The way, suggested by Nick Weinberg, installs a pretty outdated version of the driver, therefore I would suggest to download the one directly from your hardware vendor.

Since you have Intel CPU, do the following

1. Open the Intel OpenCL [drivers web-page](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/opencl-drivers), go to "Intel CPU Runtime for OpenCL™ Applications 18.1 for Linux* OS (64bit only)" and press "Download"
2. The web-site will ask you to register and login. This is mandatory. Then you will be directed to the link with tgz-archive.
3. Download this archive and install it as follows.

   ```
   tar -pvxf l_opencl_p_18.1.0.013.tgz
   cd l_opencl_p_18.1.0.013/`
   sudo ./install.sh`
   ```

   This installation script will write a lot of libraries into `/opt/intel` and will create a symbolic link (or replace the old one) `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOpenCL.so`.

My understanding of the subject is that the above steps allow OpenCL to access your Intel CPU. But if you have Intel HD Graphics, it makes sense to allow OpenCL to use this integrated graphics too. Then do the following

1. Open the Intel OpenCL [drivers web-page](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/opencl-drivers) again, but this time go to "Linux* OS Ubuntu* 16.04.x (deb)" under "Intel® Graphics Technology" section. Then you have two choices: "Download" and "Build". Use the "Download" link, it will bring you to [pre-built binaries](https://github.com/intel/compute-runtime/releases) ("Build" will bring you to the source code at Intel's github, but I have never tried to compile it from source).
2. Follow instructions given over there. I've just copied these here with one fix - use `sudo apt` instead of `sudo dpkg -i *.deb` since `dpkg` does not check dependencies:

   ```
   mkdir neo
   cd neo
   wget https://github.com/intel/compute-runtime/releases/download/19.14.12751/intel-gmmlib_19.1.1_amd64.deb
   wget https://github.com/intel/compute-runtime/releases/download/19.14.12751/intel-igc-core_19.11.1622_amd64.deb
   wget https://github.com/intel/compute-runtime/releases/download/19.14.12751/intel-igc-opencl_19.11.1622_amd64.deb
   wget https://github.com/intel/compute-runtime/releases/download/19.14.12751/intel-opencl_19.14.12751_amd64.deb
   wget https://github.com/intel/compute-runtime/releases/download/19.14.12751/intel-ocloc_19.14.12751_amd64.deb
   sudo apt install ./*deb
   ```

   Note that `.` in `./*deb` is important: without this dot you will get `Unable to locate` and `Couldn't find` errors.

P.S. the Intel website lists the suitable CPUs, make sure that yours is in this list.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to get OpenCL working for darktable on Ubuntu 19.04 x64.

Initially `darktable-cltest` reports

```
0.016782 [opencl_init] could not find opencl runtime library 'libOpenCL'
0.016851 [opencl_init] could not find opencl runtime library 'libOpenCL.so'
0.016988 [opencl_init] found opencl runtime library 'libOpenCL.so.1'
0.017020 [opencl_init] opencl library 'libOpenCL.so.1' found on your system and loaded
0.021674 [opencl_init] found 1 platform
0.077428 [opencl_init] found 1 device
0.077458 [opencl_init] discarding device 0 `Intel(R) HD Graphics 5500 BroadWell U-Processor GT2' because the driver `OpenCL 1.2 beignet 1.3' is blacklisted.
0.077464 [opencl_init] no suitable devices found.
0.077469 [opencl_init] FINALLY: opencl is NOT AVAILABLE on this system.
0.077473 [opencl_init] initial status of opencl enabled flag is OFF.
```

But after `sudo apt-get install intel-opencl-icd` it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

This thread: https://einsteinathome.org/content/quick-guide-how-install-opencl-amd-gpus-linux-kubuntu-1804-and-similar-distro resolved my problem.

> To do that you just have to go on the official AMD website and look for your drivers https://www.amd.com/en/support and download the correct Linux one, right now the recent version is 18.30, so get it and extract the content in a folder.

> Now use the terminal, move inside that folder, and just run ./amdgpu-install --opencl=legacy,pal --headless

I had to do this in addition to installing the `ocl-icd-opencl-dev` package.