# DaVinci Resolve 16 doesn't work on Ubuntu Studio 20.04 LTS

Tags: graphics, lts, ubuntu-studio, davinci-resolve

My work PC has an Intel HD Graphics 5500, it is a Lenovo t450.

DaVinci Resolve 16 doesn't work on it. I'm using Ubuntu Studio 20.04 LTS. I've tried to install `makeresolvedeb`, but it still doesn't work and shows me this message:

> DaVinci Resolve could not find any OpenCL capable GPUs. Would you like
> to review and update your DaVinci Resolve Hardware Configuration?

[image: Screenshot of DaVinci Resolve error]

Any help?

Comment: Update 

Now DaVinci Resolve 17 works onUbuntu Studio 20.04 LTS, but medias wont import. Any solution to this? I already tried all codec and format of video. 

BTW thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Now I would like to post this as a comment but I can't yet... Here are some steps that you can start with:

- Do you have `libOpenCL.so` installed and available to the app? see if there's anything missing in `ldd /opt/resolve/bin/resolve | grep OpenCL`
- If it is not installed, you might want to try installing `ocl-icd-opencl-dev`, as described here: [How to install libOpenCL.so on ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/796770/how-to-install-libopencl-so-on-ubuntu), since this package is also listed as a prerequisite for installing davinci resolve in this article: https://www.fosslinux.com/24381/how-to-install-davinci-resolve-on-ubuntu.htm
- Make sure `libOpenCL.so` is in your ldconfig cache: `ldconfig -p | grep OpenCL`, if not, update it with `ldconfig`, then run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure davinci-resolve`

If that doesn't help, this article (where I also found most of the other information) lists some more things you can try: https://bashbaug.github.io/opencl/2019/07/06/OpenCL-On-Linux.html (see section "Troubleshooting OpenCL on Linux")

Comment: Both the first and third command output something. I tried the install from the second point but all it did was uninstall `nvidia-opencl-dev` and install `ocl-icd-opencl-dev` which didn't make DaVinci work