# install amd driver on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: amd-graphics, amdgpu, amdgpu-pro

I have amd radeon hd 4350/4550 gpu,and I'm on ubuntu 20.04.
so I tried many way to install official amd driver for ubuntu but every time I get an error.
for example:
I downloaded amd driver form amd.com and i going to install requairment befor install it.

```
kernel@kernel-EP43-UD3L:~$ sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential cdbs fakeroot dh-make debhelper debconf libstdc++6 dkms libqtgui4 wget execstack libelfg0 dh-modaliases
[sudo] password for kernel: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libqtgui4 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libqtgui4' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package libelfg0
```

I get an error,what can i do for resolve it?

Comment: Why do you think you don't have drivers?

Comment: They should be automatically installed during the installation of ubuntu(if you had an internet connection)

Comment: @LevonMinasian AMD graphics drivers are open-source, included and installed even without internet connection :)

Comment: Did you find any of what was posted useful?

Answer (score 1):

One problem might be that Ubuntu 20 ships with kernel version 5.4. The kernel for your driver is limited to 3.4. Might need a different Ubuntu dist? Or maybe time for a GPU upgrade? Either way, that's probably your main issue.

I've successfully installed AMD drivers on Ubuntu 20.04 for the following cards:

- 5500 XT
- RX Vega 64

I know those cards use a different driver, so adjust the naming convention(s) accordingly. Maybe this will be helpful for someone else.

Let's get a clean install, first.

```
locate amdgpu-uninstall
```

Should be /usr/bin/amdgpu-uninstall...run it.

```
sudo /usr/bin/amdgpu-uninstall
```

If it fails to delete `/opt/amdgpu/` and/or `/opt/amdgpu-pro/` directories, then:

```
sudo rm -rf /opt/amd...
```

Here is your driver:
https://www2.ati.com/drivers/legacy/amd-driver-installer-catalyst-13.1-legacy-linux-x86.x86_64.zip

You'll need to unzip it.

```
sudo apt-get install unzip

unzip ~/Downloads/amd-driver-installer-catalyst-13.1-legacy-linux-x86.x86_64.zip

./amd-driver-installer-catalyst-13.1-legacy-linux-x86.x86_64.run
```

### [Current AMD Driver](https://www.amd.com/en/support/previous-drivers/graphics/radeon-rx-vega-series/radeon-rx-vega-series/radeon-rx-vega-64)

Again, wrong kernel, so this is probably moot.

You could try giving a different driver a whirl?

Alternatively: [Check here](https://www.amd.com/en/support)

```
tar -xvf ~/Downloads/amdgpu-pro-21.30-1290604-ubuntu-20.04.tar.xz

sudo ./amdgpu-pro-21.30-1290604-ubuntu-20.04/amdgpu-install --opencl=pal,legacy,rocr --no-dkms --headless
```

### Groups

Add yourself to render and video groups

```
sudo usermod -aG render $USER

sudo usermod -aG video $USER

sudo reboot
```

Changes won't take affect until you reboot.

Finally...

### [Darktable](https://math.dartmouth.edu/%7Esarunas/amdgpu.html)

[Darktable Benchmark](https://math.dartmouth.edu/%7Esarunas/darktable_bench.html)

```
sudo apt install darktable

sudo darktable-cltest
```

### Linux Firmware

This might also be helpful

```
git clone https://kernel.googlesource.com/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git

sudo cp ~/linux-firmware/amdgpu/* /lib/firmware/amdgpu && sudo update-initramfs -k all -u -v
```

### Troubleshooting Resources

[Folding Forum](https://foldingforum.org/viewtopic.php?t=33090)

[Random Blog](https://randomblog.hu/setting-up-your-amd-video-card-in-ubuntu-20-04/)

[Kernel Issues?](https://community.amd.com/t5/drivers-software/amdgpu-pro-20-45-amdgpu-dkms-fails-error-solution-for-ubuntu-20/td-p/458997)

### OpenCL Help

[Bashbaug](https://bashbaug.github.io/opencl/2019/07/06/OpenCL-On-Linux.html)

[Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/796770/how-to-install-libopencl-so-on-ubuntu/796773#796773)

Good luck.

May the odds be forever in your favor.

Answer (score 0):

One of many sources: https://linuxconfig.org/amd-radeon-ubuntu-20-04-driver-installation

**Ubuntu drivers**

The providing package for the driver is `xserver-xorg-video-radeon_19.1.0-1_amd64`, so you should install it with `sudo apt install xserver-xorg-video-radeon_19.1.0-1_amd64` (`apt-get` is disfavored).
This should work out-of-the-box.

**Proprietary drivers**

If you want to go with proprietary drivers, there is a [simple guide](https://ubunlog.com/en/instalar-drivers-privativos-amd-radeon-ubuntu/).
Go to the AMD Download Page, and grab the latest version of the drivers that matches your card.
Then execute (with suitable version numbers)

```
$ tar -xf amdgpu-pro_*.tar.xz
$ cd amdgpu-pro-XX.XX-XXXXXX
$ ./amdgpu-pro-install -y
```

**Third party repository**

To have the latest AMD Radeon driver version execute

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
$ sudo apt update && sudo apt -y upgrade
```

---

**TL;DR**:

**Ubuntu drivers**

From https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD

> NOTE: For Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and above, the AMD Catalyst or fglrx driver
> is no longer supported by AMD, or in Ubuntu.{1} If you have an AMD GPU
> and wish to run any Ubuntu version 16.04 LTS or newer, there are two
> open source driver options: Radeon or AMDGPU. The AMDGPU-PRO driver
> provides the open source AMDGPU driver and a proprietary overlay.
> Newer AMD GPUs designed with GCN technology (Graphics Core Next)
> should use AMDGPU or AMDGPU-PRO, while older AMD GPUs should use
> Radeon.

For the graphics card Radeon HD 4350/4550 the chipset is RV710.

According to [this official info](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man4/radeon.4.html) (or `man radeon`), that card/chipset is in the list of *SUPPORTED HARDWARE* by the `radeon` Xorg driver,
with the following features:

1. Full support for 8-, 15-, 16- and 24-bit pixel depths, and for 30-bit depth on **Linux 3.16 and later**;
2. RandR 1.2 and RandR 1.3 support;
3. Full EXA 2D acceleration;
4. Textured XVideo acceleration including anti-tearing support (Bicubic filtering only available on R/RV3xx, R/RV/RS4xx, R/RV5xx, and RS6xx/RS740);
5. 3D acceleration;

The providing package is `xserver-xorg-video-radeon_19.1.0-1_amd64`, so you should install it with `sudo apt install xserver-xorg-video-radeon_19.1.0-1_amd64` (`apt-get` is disfavored).
This should work out-of-the-box.

The problem you are quoting in the OP is `'libqtgui4' has no installation candidate`.

What makes you think you need it to have the right amd drivers for your card?
Where did you get such info/hint?
What about the other packages you are installing?

I suggest you go over the following commands one by one, and post the output in the OP, by copy-pasting text, not screen capture.
That will help solving potential problems in case the solution does not work.

```
$ sudo update-pciids
$ lspci -nn | grep -E 'VGA|Display'
$ dmesg | egrep -i 'drm|radeon'
$ sudo lshw -c video
$ lsmod | grep amd
$ glxinfo -B
```

Note: [This](https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/20.04/ubuntu-main-amd64/fglrx-pxpress_0.8.1_amd64.deb.html) is perhaps an alternative, YMMV.